# How to route audio in from other souce to Audio Jack

Tags: android, audio

[image]I have to validate the audio sent during call on the phone.
My thought for the same is like below,

1. Use standard wired headset with mic and speaker
2. Remove mic and get 2 wires from this point (which should be now your audio input)
3. Play a tone from media player of your system (computer).
4. plug a jack to audio out of your system and feed the same to your Step 2. above

But, this failed and phone was picking up audio from default mic and not from audio jack.

Please let me know if there is better way of doing this.

-Thanks in advance,
Manju

Comment: It seems to me that you have missed a few things. I recommend you post a diagram of and a better detailed explanation.

Comment: @slybloty: attached a pic of the headset, i have removed mic and tapped that line to connect my laptop audio out.

Comment: You probably can't do this with wires - likely you need a DC blocking capacitor and perhaps a resistor to activate the presence detection.  It has been covered on electronics.stackexchange.com (DO NOT ask a new question there, rather search for the existing ones on this topic)

Comment: Did you add anything else in the old mic path after removing the mic, or did you just solder on the wire that you connect to your computer? It sounds to me like your modified device is no longer being recognized as a headset (i.e. something that has a mic). You might want to read up on how headset detection works at the hardware level (try googling e.g. for "headset microphone detection"). I'm not sure this question is suited for StackOverflow since it doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.